# Get data from table on from (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a page with table.
Notice `<spring:message>` code its for i18n:

```xml
 <form method="GET" action="getData">
            <b><p align="center" ><spring:message code="block_1"/></p></b>
            <table align="center" class="main-table" border="10">

                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4"><spring:message code="subblock_1.1"/></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th><spring:message code="in_order"/></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="evaluation_criterion"/></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="number_of_points"/></th>
                    <th><spring:message code="answer"/></th>
                </tr>
                <tr><td class="column">1</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_1"/></td><td>10,00</td> <td> <input type="checkbox" unchecked name=""paraghaph_1_1_1" value="10.00"> </td> </tr>
                <tr><td class="column">2</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_2"/></td><td>9,00</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_2" value="9.00"></td> </tr>
                <tr><td class="column">3</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_3"/></td><td>8,55</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_3" value="8.55"></td> </tr>
                <tr><td class="column">4</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_4"/></td><td>8,15</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_4" value="8.15"></td> </tr>
                <tr><td class="column">5</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_5"/></td><td>7,20</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_5" value="7.20"></td> </tr>
                <tr><td class="column">6</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_6"/></td><td>6,25</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_6" value="6.25"></td> </tr>
                <tr><td class="column">7</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_7"/></td><td>5,80</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_7" value="5.80"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column">8</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_8"/></td><td>5,55</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_8" value="5.55"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column">9</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_9"/></td><td>4,50</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_9" value="4.5"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column">10</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_10"/></td><td>4,25</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="1.1.10" value="4.25"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column">11</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_11"/></td><td>3,55</td> <td><input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_1" value="3.55"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column">12</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_12"/></td><td>2,55</td> <td> <input type="checkbox" unchecked name="paraghaph_1_1_12" value="2.55"> </tr>
                <tr><td class="column">13</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_13"/></td><td>0,25</td> <td><input type="text" name="paraghaph_1_1_13"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column">14</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_14"/></td><td>0,15</td> <td><input type="text" name="paraghaph_1_1_14"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="column">15</td><td><spring:message code="paragraph_1_1_15"/></td><td>-1,00</td> <td><input type="text" name="paraghaph_1_1_15"></td></tr>
</table>
 </form>
```

And have a entity Paragraph through which I would like a `List<Paragraph>` and insert to db id.

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "paraghaph")
    public class Paragraph {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column
        private long id_paragraph;
    
        @Column
        String name;
    
        @Column
        String score;
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_subblock")
        public Subblock subblock;
    
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_paragraph")
        public List<Rating> ratings;

/* some getters and setters*/
```

I'm trying to do it by response body , but HTML tags `<tr>`,`<td>` dont have attr name on which i can mapping with Paragraph.

So my questions are:

1. How i can get all table content (or content where input is not null)?
2. To return content to table better to use jstl/core or it possible with `@RequestBody` or `RequestEntity`? (give an example please)

Answer (score 0):

If you return `@ResponseBody` then you should render the table with JavaScript on the client side on the browser. The appropriate media type is used to serialise the returned object.

If you return a view such as jsp then model attributes contains the data that is rendered by the jsp template. The jsp template is returned by the configured view resolver.

You can find examples here [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).

Next example is [Handling Form Submission](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/).

Comment: As i know @ResponseBody gets data to object by html attr "name" , as you know html tags "tr","td" dont have this attr. Maybe its possible with spring tags?

Comment: You can bind only input elements or tags that render those elements. Did you see the example?